# Exception when using mouse scoll on sub menu items

Tags: jmeter

I click on Add -> any option as Config Elements and then scroll mouse up/down

There are Uncaught exception per scroll:

```
2018-03-26 13:47:18,742 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -25
    at org.apache.jorphan.gui.MenuScroller.refreshMenu(MenuScroller.java:550) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jorphan.gui.MenuScroller.access$300(MenuScroller.java:55) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jorphan.gui.MenuScroller$MouseScrollListener.mouseWheelMoved(MenuScroller.java:576) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseWheelEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
```

Notice it happens only in sub menu and also in JMeter 3.3 and latest 4.0 versions

[image]

Option to scroll example:

[image]

**EDIT**

Error in vanilla JMeter 4.0 after change Root to log level debug :

```
2018-03-26 14:46:22,799 DEBUG o.a.j.g.GuiPackage: Updating gui to new node
2018-03-26 14:46:22,800 DEBUG o.a.j.g.GuiPackage: Showing pop up for org.apache.jmeter.gui.MainFrame$1[,0,0,374x759,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@29c29532,flags=16777704,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,editable=false,invokesStopCellEditing=false,largeModel=false,rootVisible=false,rowHeight=0,scrollsOnExpand=true,showsRootHandles=true,toggleClickCount=2,visibleRowCount=20] at x,y = 77,15
2018-03-26 14:46:24,618 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -38
    at org.apache.jorphan.gui.MenuScroller.refreshMenu(MenuScroller.java:550) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jorphan.gui.MenuScroller.access$300(MenuScroller.java:55) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jorphan.gui.MenuScroller$MouseScrollListener.mouseWheelMoved(MenuScroller.java:576) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseWheelEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventToSelf(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchMouseWheelToAncestor(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56150) in JMeter application and only occur if you open the menu and then perform scroll down action.

I would suggest not to scroll down when all options are visible and just select the option that you needed.

Comment: Sometimes not all options are visible and there's a scroller, I added a screenshot

Comment: Yes, please attach a screenshot or tell me the option. I can suggest the workaround.

Comment: Option is available by adding several listeners' plugins

Comment: Are you able to scroll down by clicking arrow icon showing at the bottom of the menu list. [Dont use mouse scroller]

Answer (score -2):

1. JMeter [issue tracker](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) is at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/, not here
2. The issue cannot be reproduced on vanilla JMeter 4.0 and 3.3 so kindly update your question with contents of "lib" and "lib/ext" folders of your JMeter installation. You will be asked the same by JMeter developers as well as JMeter logs with increased level of verbosity, you will need to change `<Root level="info">` to i.e. `<Root level="debug">` in *log4j2.xml* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)
3. The recommended way of installing JMeter Plugins is via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Thank you for responding .1. I'll start posting to bugzilla,2. happens on vanilla JMeter, for example scroll down when mouse is over `Thread Group` sub menu. - added new log with debug level 3. no need for plugin manager